# Can I debug a program with LLDB-MI via Eclipse?

Tags: linux, eclipse, lldb

It seems that LLDB plugin for Eclipse is still not developed yet, but [this](https://www.codeplay.com/portal/lldb-mi-driver---part-2-setting-up-the-driver) article claims that one can debug a program with LLDB-MI driver in Linux. However described way of integrating Eclipse and LLDB doesn't work for me (I always get "command --exec-continue not recognized" error message) and it looks suspicious that embedding LLDB-MI to Eclipse may be so easy.

Could anyone point me to curren materials on this topic? Google shows me only old Eclipse-bug-tracking threads.

Answer (score 0):

There is a project called lldbmi2 that provides most of the functionality one would need.  I know it's been developed primarily for the Mac and I don't know if it's been tested on Linux.  It's not perfect, but I've been using it on the Mac for months and I'm pleased with its functionality.

See https://github.com/freedib/lldbmi2